# First Order Logic - I'm having trouble understanding what this question is asking of me. Don't need answers, just an example.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I'm having trouble understanding what this question is asking of me, I know what the parts listed are; referents, predicates, etc, but not what order it is wanting them listed. I don't need someone to give me the answers for this, just an example or something to point me in the correct direction. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: hi @H_Otacon; welcome to math.stackexchange! since Noah's answer below was helpful you may want to "[accept](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer)" it by ticking the green checkmark to its left :)

Answer (score 5):

That is indeed a rather unclearly presented question, in my opinion!

---

First, a quick recap of the picture the questions are about.

The picture is describing a structure. Remember that a structure consists of three parts: an *underlying set*, a *language*, and an *interpretation of that language on the underlying set*. The underlying set of the structure is $\{1,2,3,4\}$; the lowercase letters are constant symbols, $F$ and $G$ are unary relation (= one-place predicate) symbols, and $R$ is a binary relation symbol; and the interpretations of each symbol are indicated by the picture, albeit rather unclearly. Specifically:

The interpretations of the constant symbols are indicated by their placement: e.g. the symbol "$b$" is placed next to the element $1$, indicating that that's the element of the structure it gets interpreted as. For example, the constant symbol $b$ gets interpreted as the element $1$ in this structure.

The interpretations of $F$ and $G$ are given by the "blobs" next to each. So e.g. $F$'s interpretation, the left blob, contains $1$ and $3$ but not $2$ or $4$.

The interpretation of $R$ is given by arrows: an arrow from $x$ to $y$ indicates that $R$ holds of the pair $(x,y)$. Note that arrows in general are not bi-directional; a bi-directional arrow indicates that both $(x,y)$ and $(y,x)$ are in $R$. So for example $(1,3)$ is in $R$ but $(3,1)$ is not in $R$.

---

Now we come to the questions themselves.

Each question is asking you how a particular symbol is interpreted in the structure described by the picture - specifically, the symbol being asked about in a given question is the part of that question right before the colon. So the first question is asking you how the constant symbol $a$ is interpreted and the last question is asking you how the unary relation symbol $G$ is interpreted.

For constant symbols, this is easy: just write down the element named by the symbol. So for question $b$, you write down the element named by $b$, which is

> $1$.

For unary relation symbols things are a bit more complicated, since the interpretation of a unary relation symbol is a *set of* elements. Here the instruction says to write your answer as a list of numbers in increasing order separated by commas but no spaces, so e.g. "1,3,4" or "2,3" but not "3,2" or "1, 3, 4." In particular, the answer to question $G$ is

> "2,3."

Comment: Thank you for the help, this is exactly what I needed.